# OpenSSL 1.0 или 1.1

Tags: php, docker, openssl, sqlsrv

Имеется проект c `PHP 7.2` и пакетом `sqlsrv-5.8.1` версии. Пакет этот использует `OpenSSL` версии `1.1.1s`. Мне необходимо было обновить версию `PHP` до `8.2`. Но `sqlsrv` версии `5.8.1` не поддерживается в этой версии пыхи. Решил скачать последнюю версию `sqlsrv`. Она использует `OpenSSL 3.0.7`. После того как я запустил сервер, мне выдает ошибку:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [OpenSSL
> library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is
> installed].

Как мне решить этот конфликт? После версии `sqlsrv 5.8.1` из стабильных идёт `5.9.0`, но она также не поддерживается в `PHP 8.2`. Следующая версия `5.10.0`, но в ней используется `OpenSSL 3.0.7`.

Comment: в тагах докер - показывай докерфайл.